# Set colour of all agents inside a list Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, adhoc

I've got a list set up called nodes, and inside this are 50 randomly distributed sensor ids. This part is working fine, the problem I am having is how do I action this list, for example later in the program change the color of every sensor in the list to black? This is what I currently have based on the who command but it doesn't work. Any help I would really appreciate it, hoping it is something simple for someone with know-how.

**ask sensors with [who = nodes] [set color black]**

Answer (score 0):

In NetLogo, you basically always want to use an agentset instead of a list of who numbers.  A list of who numbers might be a good way to solve something in a different programming language, but not in NetLogo.

If you have an agentset, you can simply `ask` it directly.

So for example:

```
ask n-of 50 sensors [ set color black ]
```

Here, `n-of 50 sensors` is an agentset of 50 randomly selected sensors.